# Solr custom Transformer

Tags: java, solr, indexing

I'm quite new to solr and till now i only use it to index data from DB. Now I'm trying to write a custom Transformer. I've read the documentation at http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DIHCustomTransformer, but i can't figure out how to configure it to be visible from the DIH.

My purpose is to index uploaded images data. Some information comes from a db, for example the owner of the image or the path where the file is stored. Other information, mostly metadata, are extracted from the image file. My idea is to set a dataInputHandler that extracts data from db, and a Transformer that extracts metadata and puts it in the solr document.

Can someone explain me how custom transformers works?

Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class will have to be available on the class path visible to Solr, usually through a .jar file available in one of the configured `lib` directories (or you can add your own to your solr configuration file (solrconfig.xml - any paths will be relative to this file in a `<lib>` entry). See [How to Load Plugins](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrPlugins#How_to_Load_Plugins) for more information about how Solr finds your plugin code.

Your transformer will then receive the whole row from the DB, where you can read the file path and add new columns to the row returned to the DIH importer to be included in your document.

Comment: Hi MatsLindh thank you for the reply. In my solrconfig.xml i have this row: 
  <lib dir="../lib/" regex="imageMetaDataExtractorTransformer.jar"/>. In lib i have the imageMetaDataExtractorTransformer.jar that contains this code: import java.util.List; 
import java.util.Map; 

public class imageMetaDataExtractorTransformer{
        
        public Object transformRow(Map<String, Object> row){   
                row.put("user_id", "test_transformer");
                return row;
        }
}

Comment: in my data-config <entity> tag i have trasformer="imageMetaDataExtractorTransformer".I'm expecting the user_id field to change from DB value to "test_transformer", but till now nothing append. Am I missing something?

Comment: Does your code get called at all? (add a few System.out.println() and watch the standard output from the container) You'll also need the full package/class name of your class (if you have a package; entry)

Comment: Seems that solr ignores my transformer, i try to add a System.out.println but nothing comes out in standard output. I try to write it with an IDE (intellij).

Comment: here my new code with dependences and with my package: `package com.mycustompackage.solr;
import org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.Context;
import org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.Transformer;
import java.util.Map;
public class ImageTransformer extends Transformer{
    @Override
    public Object transformRow(Map<String, Object> row, Context context){
        row.put("test_transformer", "test_transformer");
        row.remove("user_id");
        row.put("user_id","test");
        System.out.println(row.get("user_id"));
        return row;
    }
}`